# Filtering resources when using resourcegroupstaggingapi CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to find resources in my AWS based on certain tag conditions. I have been using `jq` to achieve it but is there way of using `resourcegroupstaggingapi` so they provide a direct way to filter resources where any of the specified tags is missing.

I have 2 use cases and this is how I've been filtering them using jq :

1. When SV tag exists but DM does not : `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList | map(select(.Tags[] | select(.Key == "SV") and select(.Key != "DM")))'`
2. When either of CostCenter, Environment or Team tag does not exist : `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList | map(select(.Tags[] | (.Key | IN("CostCenter", "Environment", "Team",) | not)))'`

I tried doing the same without using jq like this :

1. When SV tag exists but DM does not : `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters "Key=SV,Values=*" "Key=DM,Values=NULL"`
2. When either of CostCenter, Environment or Team tag does not exist : `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters "Key=CostCenter,Values=" "Key=Environment,Values=" "Key=Team,Values="`

But with jq I am able to get the output for both however without jq, I just get empty result for both

```
{
    "ResourceTagMappingList": []
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tag-filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html#options) option does not seem to support negation. As a workaround, you can use the `--query` client side filtering option with the `not_null` function.

So for the condition *"When SV tag exists but DM does not"* you can use:

```bash
$ aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 --query \
'ResourceTagMappingList[?not_null(Tags[?Key==`SV`]) && !not_null(Tags[?Key==`DM`])]'
```

and for the condition *"When either of CostCenter, Environment or Team tag does not exist"* you can use:

```bash
$ aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 --query \
'ResourceTagMappingList[?!not_null(Tags[?Key==`CostCenter`]) || !not_null(Tags[?Key==`Environment`]) || !not_null(Tags[?Key==`Team`])]'
```

Comment: A client-side query filtering is certainly more direct than my server-side lambda approach. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

As VonC said, there isn't a way to filter resources using `resourcegroupstaggingapi`, however for your first use case for When SV tag exists but DM does not, the jq query should be :

`jq '.ResourceTagMappingList | map(select(any(.Tags[]; .Key == "SV") and all(.Tags[]; .Key != "DM")))'`